# Force specific WooCommerce product to be sold in separate order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm trying to force a specific product in WooCommerce to be sold separately.
I however want this product to sell in unlimited quantity.

Based on [Force sold individually product to be bought alone in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236937/11987538) answer code which works quite well, I am currently using:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Product id to bought alone 
    $product_id_alone = 666;
 
    // Set variable
    $alone = true;
 
    // If passed
    if ( $passed ) {
        // If cart is NOT empty when a product is added
        if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
 
            // If product id added = product id alone
            if ( $product_id_alone == $product_id ) {
                $alone = false;
            } else {
                // Generate a unique ID for the cart item
                $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id_alone );
 
                // Check if product is in the cart
                $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
 
                // If product is already in cart
                if ( $in_cart ) {
                    $alone = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
 
            if ( $product_id_alone == $product_id) {
                $alone = true;         
            }
        }
    }
 
    if ( $alone == false ) {
        // Set error message
        $message = 'Product 666 must be bought separately.';
        wc_add_notice( __( $message, 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
 
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

---

If the cart is empty, I can add product with ID 666 with a custom quantity.

Once product ID 666 has been added to the cart, I can't add another product to the cart.

And if I start by adding another product to an empty cart, I can't add product ID 666 to the cart.

The issue is that if I add product ID 666 to an empty cart I can't increase quantity of product 666 by adding more of that product into the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force a specific product to be sold alone, in a separate order, use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Product id to bought alone 
    $product_id_alone = 666;

    // Set variable
    $flag = false;

    // If cart is NOT empty when a product is added
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Generate a unique ID for the cart item
        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id_alone );

        // Check if product is in the cart
        $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

        // If product is already in cart & product ID added is not equal to product ID alone
        if ( $in_cart && ( $product_id != $product_id_alone ) ) {
            $flag = true;
        // Product ID alone is NOT in cart & product ID added is equal to product ID alone
        } elseif( ! $in_cart && ( $product_id == $product_id_alone ) ) {
            $flag = true;
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        // Set error message
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            __( 'Product %s must be bought separately', 'woocommerce' ),
            $product_id_alone,
        ), 'error' );

        // Passed = false
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

---

When adding the product with ID 666:

- If the cart is empty, the product can be added with any quantity.
- If the cart is not empty & the product with ID 666 is NOT in cart, stop.
- If the cart is not empty & the product with ID 666 is in cart, continue.

When a product with a different ID is added:

- If the cart is empty, the product can be added with any quantity.
- If the cart is not empty & the product with ID 666 is NOT in cart, continue.
- If the cart is not empty & the product with ID 666 is in cart, stop.

Answer (score -1):

This is my script that prevents products of a certain type from being placed in the same order with those of another, based on the value of a certain tag

```
function wc_giftcard_with_own_order( $passed_validation, $product_id ) {
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    
    if ( empty($cart) ) {
        // carrello vuoto, per cui passa
        return $passed_validation;
    }
    
    // carrello non vuoto
    // conta quanti prodotti sono di tipo gift card e quanti no
    // tag "gift card" = ID tag 340
    $coupon_si = 0;
    $coupon_no = 0;
    
    foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item )
        if ( has_term( 340, 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $coupon_si += 1;
        }
        else {
            $coupon_no += 1;
        }
        
    // se il prodotto corrente è una gift card, allora può essere aggiunto ad un carrello con soli articole gift card
    // se il prodotto corrente non è una gift card, allora può essere aggiunto ad un carrello con soli articoli non gift card
    if ( has_term( 340, 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
        if ( $coupon_no == 0 ) {
            return $passed_validation;
        }
        else {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'La gift card NON può essere acquistata con altri prodotti', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( $coupon_si == 0 ) {
            return $passed_validation;
        }
        else {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'In ordine esiste già almeno una gift card, che NON può essere acquistata con altri prodotti', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return $passed_validation;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'wc_giftcard_with_own_order', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to apply to the question, why did you post this here? 
there is no mention of product tags at all in the question